# How does iterative DFS traverse back?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

The following program find the path that sum to a given number.

```
def hasPathSum(self, root, sum):
    if root is None:
        return False
    stack = [(root, sum)]
    while stack:
        node, _sum = stack.pop()
        if node.left is node.right is None and node.val == _sum:
            return True
        if node.left:
            stack.append((node.left, _sum - node.val))
        if node.right:
            stack.append((node.right, _sum - node.val))
    return False
```

It uses iterative DFS with a stack. I understand most part of the program, but I do not know how does it traverse back, if the leaf node is reached.

I suppose the only way to traverse back is to call the function for every node. And that is the reason we call it iterative. Do my understanding right and complete? Or more precisely, we do not traverse back. We simply start over from a new child node.

If it is true, then we are wasting our time by re-visiting many paths, aren't we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a lot easier to see what's going on here by looking at which nodes are on the stack as the algorithm executes. For example, let's suppose that we have this tree:

```
           A
          / \
         B   C
            / \
           D   E
```

We begin with the stack containing A:

```
           A
          / \
         B   C    Stack: A
            / \
           D   E
```

We pop A off the stack and push on B and C:

```
           A
          / \
         B   C    Stack: B, C
            / \
           D   E
```

Now, we pop C off the stack and push D and E:

```
           A
          / \
         B   C    Stack: B, D, E
            / \
           D   E
```

Now, we pop E off the stack. At this point, we're at a leaf, so we don't add anything more to the tree.

```
           A
          / \
         B   C    Stack: B, D
            / \
           D   E
```

You asked about how we "back up" at this point. There's nothing explicitly here that will make us "back up," but rather we'll just pop the next node off the stack and continue looking there. That next node is D, so we've effectively backed up through C and are now trying out node D.

Since D also has no children, we just pop it from the stack:

```
           A
          / \
         B   C    Stack: B
            / \
           D   E
```

The top of the stack is now B, so we've implicitly "backed up" to A, then explored the next of A's children, B. B has no children, so we pop it off the stack and the exploration terminates.

Hopefully this gives you a sense of how the backing up occurs - when many nodes are pushed onto the stack, only one of them is explored and the remainder are deferred until a later time. The backing up is then implemented implicitly by "jumping back" to another node that was discovered earlier but not visited.

The specific DFS code you have here does some extra processing at each level to track the remaining sum as it goes, and I'll leave it as an Exercise to the Reader to see how that works.

In the meantime, though, do note that tracing through code with pictures like these is often the best way to figure out what a piece of code actually does. It's very hard to read the code in isolation and see its effect, but by drawing the right picture its execution and behavior can become a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/iterativedeepeningsearch-141221081041-conversion-gate01/95/iterative-deepening-search-16-638.jpg?cb=1419149544) you can see an image of how iterative deepening search works.

It visits the nodes in the search tree in the same order as depth-first search, but the cumulative order in which nodes are first visited is effectively breadth-first.

It returns to the root node and increases the depth of the search.

**In the programm above** i think sum value defines how far the algorithm will search starting from the root node.So i guess to traverse back you should call the function again with the same root value and the sum value increased.

Comment: I don't believe this code uses iterative deepening, and the sum only comes into play when it hits a leaf, so I'm not sure the link you've provided or the explanation you've included here are relevant for the question.